# how i can execute async code in sequence?

Tags: node.js, async-await, fs

```
    await fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, "/smartsheet_download"), 
   { recursive: true }, (err) => { 
     if (err) { 
       return console.error(err); 
     } 
     __dirname= path.join(__dirname, "/smartsheet_download");
   console.log("after func:" + __dirname);
   })

   console.log("this must be printed after path at last")
}
```

my question in this above function is i am printing "this must be printed after path at last" after the fs.mkdir operation but when i am running the code it prints first. i am using async and await so that it must wait for fs.mkdir to complete the execution before printing the last line. Still this thing does not work. Could u please tell how can i wait for fs.mkdir to complete and then pass the execution to next line. moreover, please tell why await do not work here?

Comment: async await doesnt work on callbacks, it works on promises witch you havent

Comment: also there is `mkdirSync´ for synchronous purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your logic is correct. however, if you look at the signature of `fs.mikdir` it returns void

```
export function mkdir(path: PathLike, options: MakeDirectoryOptions & { recursive: true }, callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException | null, path: string) => void): void; <---
```

which means, it cannot be `await`ed, although it executes an async task, but due it returns void, it cannot be awaited.

the callback exists for when you need to know if the what happend to the operation, succesed/faild something like that, thats why your log happens before, because mkdir returns void.

so if you need do something after `fs.mikdir` was finished. you can use `fs.mkdirSync` which will block execution of code untill the call has finsished, or just do your work in the callback you pass to the function

```
fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, "/smartsheet_download"), 
   { recursive: true }, (err) => { 
     if (err) { 
       return console.error(err); 
     } 
     __dirname= path.join(__dirname, "/smartsheet_download");
   console.log("after func:" + __dirname);

 console.log("this must be printed after path at last")
   })
```

Comment: hi i used mkdirSync but , it stop using the callback given inside the mkdir.  could you please help ? so i can assume that if i use mkdirSync it will always create the directory first then pass the control to next line?

Comment: since `mikdirSync` stops execution of code, then there is no need for the callback, the lines after the call to `mikdirSync` will be executed if and only if the `mikdirSync` call was successful

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!!